# Significance shifts when cases are excluded

Tags: logistic-regression

I have a county level dataset with a dichotomous variable which represents whether or not any charter schools exist in a county.  I am performing a nested logistic regression. That variable is the response and the explanatory variables are social factors such as education level, language spoken at home, household type, etc.  When I include all counties in the U.S. (Including ten states which have no charter authorization laws and thus every county in those states is represented as a zero in the response variable) my results show significant associations between the response and the explanatory variables.  When I exclude those ten states the significance disappears.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you came across [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox). Roughly speaking you have a result in one group of data but not when you look at different groups or subsets. This often happens when the variables depend on hidden dimensions in the data.

The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) explains it a bit better and in more detail.